# Shulker Shells Drop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a command that makes every shulker always drop 2 shells but I can't get the command to work. I made all shulkers wear on the head shells but for some reason even though they have them on the head and the drop is 100% drop they don't drop the shells. I tried with zombies too, I gave them glass on the head but same thing anyone know how to make the shulkers drop 2 shells?

Here's the command I'm using:

```
/replaceitem entity @e[type=Shulker] slot.armor.head minecraft:shulker_shell 2 0 {ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,1.0F]}
```

Comment: Could you paste the command you're trying that isn't working?

Comment: /replaceitem entity @e[type=Shulker] slot.armor.head minecraft:shulker_shell 2 0 {ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,1.0F]}    the idea is that since the shulker has thos 2 shells always will drop 2 shells and some times 3 because shulkers drop 1 shell some times i heard in a video in hermitcraft that xisuma made shulkers always drop 2 shells with the loot table i tryed tto find someone that showed this methode but i didn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NBT data for `/replaceitem` is what should be applied to the *item*, not the entity. The item will instead have a custom `ArmorDropChances` tag that doesn't do anything.

You'll instead need to use `/entitydata` on the shulkers, where you can also change their equipment directly. The following will modify a shulker's data a single time:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Shulker,tag=!processed] {ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:shulker_shell",Count:2b}],ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,1.0F]}
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Shulker,tag=!processed] add processed
```

Or if you do not have any other scoreboard tags on the shulkers, you can use a single command (which will delete all other tags):

```
/entitydata @e[type=Shulker,tag=!processed] {ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:shulker_shell",Count:2b}],ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,1.0F],Tags:["processed"]}
```

Comment: thanks skylinerw i tested the command and now all shulkers drop the 2 shells thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself, but you could make a test for/scoreboard to check if a Shulker's health is zero, then kill all items near it (r=1)? Next, summon in 2 shells there.

Comment: i am not very good with commands and i don't know how to make this but it's a good idea it might work

Comment: This will not work because you cannot target dead entities (i.e. when their health is zero).

Comment: @Skylinerw Oh, I thought that would work because I had done that with plugins and it would work fine. Since both plugins and command blocks are server side, I thought they would reference the same entity type. 